# Using an Array at a specific index in a method in java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I am making a game called Light out! I would like to create a method that changes the color of a button at a certain index. to do this, ive used the following code:

```
Color bg = _buttons[x][y].getBackground();
            if(bg.equals(Color.white)){
                _buttons[x][y].setBackground(Color.yellow); 
            }
            else if (bg.equals(Color.yellow)){
                _buttons[x][y].setBackground(Color.white);
```

x and y are integers that are the currant value I am looking at. 
basically I would like to make a method that takes in whatever index I am at. I tried doing

```
public void flipIt(JButton _buttons[this] [this]){

            Color bg = _buttons[this][this].getBackground();


            }
```

but java doesnt like that, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you intend to call this method? (e.g. will you pass it the button instance or the `x` and `y` integers)

Comment: @khelwood Sorry i should've been more clear, I want to do this:   button[x][y].flipIt();  x and y are part of my action listener in this case so they change depending on which button ive pressed in my GUI

Comment: If you want to add a member function on your button itself, then your button needs to be an instance of a class you write yourself, and that class should provide a function `flipIt()`. In that function, the button would be `this`, and the `x`,`y` would not be referenced at all.

Comment: Java doesn't like it? Like what? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the event that you event listener picks up is a click on the button in question, you don’t need go through x and y:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object eventSource = e.getSource();
    if (eventSource instanceof JButton) {
        JButton buttonClicked = (JButton) eventSource;
        Color bg = buttonClicked.getBackground();
        if (bg.equals(Color.white)) {
            buttonClicked.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        } else if (bg.equals(Color.yellow)) {
            buttonClicked.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your calling code you could do this :

```
flipIt(_buttons[x][y]);
```

and your function would look like this

```
`public void flipIt(JButton button){
    if(button.getBackground().equals(Color.white)){
            button.setBackground(Color.yellow); 
    } else if (button.getBackground().equals(Color.yellow)){
                 button.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
 }'
```